# Set the date in Camera Roll to the value from EXIF

Tags: exif, camera-roll

When I import photos directly from my Sony a7 camera they are saved in the Camera Roll with the date/time of the import. The correct date/time is still preserved in the EXIF within the image, but I fail to find an easy way to convince iPhone to adjust the Camera Roll to that date.

Is there a way to use the date/time from EXIF to modify Camera Roll date/time?

Comment: I don’t believe you can.  There is the system created date that indicates when the file was first created and of course, the EXIF data which.  When you import a file, it’s not simply a “copy” action.  There is some processing taking place thus a new file is created and will have the import date as it’s creation date.

Comment: I wonder... aren't there actually two "layers" of metadata in most graphics/picture files?; that is the metadata that is embedded in the file itself, and the metadata added by the filesystem/operating system? And which one does the iPhone depend on for the data?